# How to Pass Parameters with Commas in Less

Tags: css, less, less-mixins

I have a mixin that takes the name of the shape and its coordinates. I am wondering how would I pass in my coordinates if the coordinates contains commas?

```
.clip-path(@shape @coords) {
    -webkit-clip-path: @shape(@coords);
       -moz-clip-path: @shape(@coords);
            clip-path: @shape(@coords);
}

.foo {
  .clip-path(polygon, 0 0, 0 100%, 100% 0);

  /*
     I am trying to achieve:
     clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 0);
  */
}
```

Comment: I don't think Firefox requires a prefix, but it also does not support shapes AFAIK. Also, I assume you know that this will not work in IE. In any case, instead of writing a LESS mixin for every property that might need prefixing, I suggest adding a prefixing tool to your toolchain, which will add all the right prefixes, in the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note:** I second all comments made by torazaburo. Please don't use Less mixins as a way to add prefixes. It is much more simpler to use a prefixing tool like AutoPrefixer or Prefix-free.

That said, below are a few ways in which you can achieve the output that you are looking for:

```css
.clip-path(@shape, @coords) {
  -webkit-clip-path: ~"@{shape}(@{coords})";
  -moz-clip-path: ~"@{shape}(@{coords})";
  clip-path: ~"@{shape}(@{coords})"; /* use interpolation to display the output */
}

.foo {
  .clip-path(polygon, ~"0 0, 0 100%, 100% 0"); /* pass the values as one single string */
}
```

Or, use the [advanced `@rest` variable option](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-advanced-arguments-and-the-rest-variable) like below. This is a way to pass variable number of args to a mixin and still make it match the mixin definition.

```css
.clip-path(@shape; @coords...) {
  -webkit-clip-path: ~"@{shape}(@{coords})";
  -moz-clip-path: ~"@{shape}(@{coords})";
  clip-path: ~"@{shape}(@{coords})";
}

.foo {
  .clip-path(polygon; 0 0, 0 100%, 100% 0);
}
.foo2 {
  .clip-path(polygon; 0 0, 0 100%, 100% 0, 100% 100%); /* Less compiler will pick all values after the first as coords */
}
```

Alternately, if the mixin is only to add vendor prefixes (which I don't recommend as mentioned earlier), the simplest option would be the below:

```css
.clip-path(@args) {
  -webkit-clip-path: @args;
  -moz-clip-path: @args;
  clip-path: @args;
}

.foo {
  .clip-path(~"polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 0)"); /* just pass the whole thing as a string */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One work around is to use a temporary variable:

```
.foo {
  @workAround: 0 0, 0 100%, 100% 0;
  .clip-path(polygon, @workAround);
}
```

You can also escape the value when you pass the variable into the mixin:

```
.foo {
  .clip-path(polygon, ~"0 0, 0 100%, 100% 0");
}
```

These both ensure that the value passed to the mixin is a string.